# How to connect user with icloud dashboard

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hello everyone i am new to cloudkit ,my direct question is how to connect the user with my cloudkit container.
I want to add him to user records through programatically.
I already login him with appleid from simulator but still it would not create a record in cloudkit dashboard.
I want to access the record id of new user while launching
 the app .
Hope you understand my question.
Thanks

Comment: Please post what you have done so far

Comment: It works in my user id and password properly but while i am doing with testing purpose for new user it will not integrated with my app.